# SSL Error: Bad handshake

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I keep getting `SSLError: ('bad handshake SysCallError(0, None))` anytime I try to make a request with python requests in my django app.
What could possibly be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did bunch of things but I believe `pip uninstall pyopenssl` did the trick