# Python requests gives me "bad handshake" error

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

Using Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) like this

```
import requests;
requests.get('https://internal.site.no')
```

gives me an error [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085552/sslerror-bad-handshake-python-requests) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009692/ssl-error-bad-handshake) [had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004748/how-to-fix-bad-handshake-sslerrors-when-utilizing-python-requests);

```
SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)
```

however, none of the missing package they suggest works. Even setting `verify=False` gives me the same error.
Curl gives me no error trying to access the same site.

Versions:

- Alpine 3.4
- requests 2.12.1 (it works in 2.11.1)
- OpenSSL 1.0.2j 26 sep 2016

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most likely error is that `requests` and the server are not able to negotiate a cipher to use.

Check what curl uses;

```
curl --verbose https://internal.site.no/
```

It will give you a lot of output, but the one you are looking for is something like `SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`.

Looking at the diff from [2.11.1 to 2.12.0](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/compare/v2.11.1...v2.12.0) of requests, shows a new version of urllib3 (to version 1.19). Maybe it's the [removal of 3des](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/commit/02c5d965d0f8c64b67c4067c9d650754ef644781#diff-8b6e87f6b5a8da0b15b37afaded9ac60) that bites you here?

If you check your `curl --verbose ...` output used cipher against [this](https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html) usefull list of cipher name mapping. You can try adding the `openssl` name of the name to what `requests` accept, example (you can do this in the beginning of your app/script):

```
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':ADH-AES128-SHA256'
```

if curl shows you that it is using `TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` (as an example).

Another handy tip is to use the nmap script [ssl-enum-ciphers](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html), like this:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 internal.site.no
```

to get a list of what it finds as supported ciphers (note, script might be noisy)...

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same issue. Check which version of requests you are using.

```
import requests
print requests.__version__
```

You should try downgrading to version 2.11.1. I did this, and it fixed my problem. To do this, issue the following commands in the terminal

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests==2.11.1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then it is probably the removal of 3des from urllib3 that was biting you as well. The the link in my answer for diff. I think it is a better solution to monkeypatch the `DEFAULT_CIPHERS` in urllib3 than being stuck on an old version. The problem lies in the `https` server we are talking to tho. It's a reason why 3des is out.. :)

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Only this solution worked for me after trying so much different things.