# Max retries exceeded with url requests Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to web scrape this page and the code i use is this:

```
page = get("https://www.uobgroup.com/online-rates/gold-and-silver-prices.page")
```

I get this error when i run this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lakesh/WebScraping/Gold.py", line 46, in <module>
    page = get("https://www.uobgroup.com/online-rates/gold-and-silver-prices.page")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 511, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.uobgroup.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /online-rates/gold-and-silver-prices.page (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)'),))
```

Tried this as well:

```
page = get("https://www.uobgroup.com/online-rates/gold-and-silver-prices.page",verify=False)
```

This doesn't work as well. Need some guidance.

Full code:

```
from requests import get
import requests
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict
import json

requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
page = get("https://www.uobgroup.com/online-rates/gold-and-silver-prices.page")
html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = defaultdict(list)
last_table = html.find_all('table')[-1]
```

Comment: You might get some guidance from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991891/python3-and-requests-still-getting-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure

Comment: requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DES-CBC3-SHA' tried this and got this error: name 'requests' is not defined

Comment: I'm guessing from the stacktrace that your code likely has a `from requests import get`. If that's the case, add an `import requests`.

Comment: still can't get the data. posted my code as well.

Comment: The guidance I was hinting at is that the site may be doing something odd with which cipher(s) it accepts. `curl -v ...` shows that site accepting a connection with DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

I added the `verify=False` option, and also took out the line that is setting the cypher.  Once I did this, your code worked for me in Python 3...sometimes.  It works once, and then seems to not work for a while.  My guess is that the site is rate-limiting access, possibly based on the agent signature it sees, trying to limit bot access.  I printed `last_table` when it worked, and here's what I got:

```
<table class="responsive-table-rates table table-striped table-bordered" id="nova-funds-list-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #002265; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;">DESCRIPTION</td>
<td style="background-color: #002265; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;">CURRENCY</td>
<td style="background-color: #002265; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;">UNIT</td>
<td style="background-color: #002265; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;">BANK SELLS</td>
<td style="background-color: #002265; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;">BANK BUYS</td>
<td style="text-align: left; display: none;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: left; display: none;"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am dumping the incoming contents to a file.  When it works, I get readable HTML.  When it doesn't work, I get a few readable lines at the top, and then a bunch of gibberish that may be some complex Javascript.  Not sure what that is.  When it doesn't work, I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/stevenjohnson/lab/so/ReadAFile.py", line 8, in 
>       last_table = html.find_all('table')[-1] IndexError: list index out of range

I get back a 200 status code in either case.

Here's my version of the code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict

page = get("https://www.uobgroup.com/online-rates/gold-and-silver-prices.page", verify=False)
html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = defaultdict(list)
last_table = html.find_all('table')[-1]
print(last_table)
```

I'm on a Mac. Maybe you're not, and the certificate chains on your machine are different than on mine, and so you're not able to get as far as I can.  I wanted you to know, however, that your code does work for me with just `verify=False`.

Comment: Well, then I don't know what's going on.  It runs fine for me on my Mac under Python 2.716 and 3.7.3.  I'm running High Sierra. - I'm running bs4-0.0.1.

Comment: My code is the same as yours, except that I added `verify=False` to the end of the `get` call. - It's running consistently now for me.  Have you tried lately?  Maybe it was something with the site.

Comment: Oh wait! .. My code isn't the same.  I commented out the `requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
` line. - I'll post my code...

Comment: Not it's not working again.  Something is flakey with this site I think. - worked again.  It's very random as to when it works and when it doesn't. - I don't think it's the number of accesses.  I just ran it successfully 8 times in a row, and then it failed on the 9th attempt.

Comment: Oh...BTW...I'm not getting an authentication or SSL error.  I'm always getting back content.  I'm just sometimes getting back an error page, or so it seems.

Comment: I added the error I'm getting when it doesn't work to my answer.  It's a parse error because I'm getting back a different page that doesn't have a table in it.

Comment: bummer.  probably something about your SSL setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192507/discussion-between-lakesh-and-steve).